# Custom API Gateway Authorizer using terraform

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, terraform

Am trying to deploy a API Gateway REST API which uses a custom authorizer using terraform.

The custom authorizer uses an existing lambda function.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_authorizer" "accountprofileauth" {
  name                   = "auth"
  rest_api_id            = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.accountprofileapi.id}"
  authorizer_uri         = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:XXXX:function:dev-authorizer"
  identity_source        = "method.request.header.Authorization"
  type                   = "REQUEST"
}
```

When i did terraform apply, i got the below error

```
* aws_api_gateway_authorizer.accountprofileauth: Error creating API Gateway Authorizer: BadRequestException: Invalid Authorizer URI: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:XXXX:function:dev-authorizer. Authorizer URI should be a valid API Gateway ARN that represents a Lambda function invocation.
    status code: 400, request id: XXXX
```

The lambda function exists and it works fine. The same arn works fine when i deploy using serverless.

Do you know the format/provide an example of valid arn?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

I found the actual format to be

> arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-2:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:XXXX:function:dev-authorizer/invocations

Looks like the date is kinda hard coded. I was confused by that :)

Comment: This was incredibly helpful. They could really do a better job of documenting this...

Comment: can you please add details how did you overcome adding permissions problem? My terraform apply command is waiting endlessly. I suspect this endless wait is due to the authorizer-credentials not having any role mentioned and the authorizer creation is stuck with prompt of granting necessary lambda invoke permissions

Comment: thank you for this tip! I also found this is mentioned on the following documentation by digging couple of hours: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-custom-integrations.html

Answer (score 2):

You can reference AWS document [Amazon Resource Names (ARNs) and AWS Service Namespaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html)

For lambda

AWS Lambda (Lambda)

```
Syntax:

arn:aws:lambda:region:account-id:function:function-name
arn:aws:lambda:region:account-id:function:function-name:alias-name
arn:aws:lambda:region:account-id:function:function-name:version
arn:aws:lambda:region:account-id:event-source-mappings:event-source-mapping-id
```

Examples:

```
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:ProcessKinesisRecords
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:ProcessKinesisRecords:your alias
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:ProcessKinesisRecords:1.0
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:event-source-mappings:kinesis-stream-arn
```

If you create labmda function within terraform as well (not in your case, but I recommend to manage all aws resources in terraform, if you already start using it)

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "authorizer" {
  filename         = "lambda-function.zip"
  source_code_hash = "${base64sha256(file("lambda-function.zip"))}"
  function_name    = "api_gateway_authorizer"
  role             = "${aws_iam_role.lambda.arn}"
  handler          = "exports.example"
}
```

You can easily reference lambda arn as `authorizer_uri`

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_authorizer" "demo" {
  name                   = "demo"
  rest_api_id            = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.demo.id}"
  authorizer_uri         = "${aws_lambda_function.authorizer.invoke_arn}"
  authorizer_credentials = "${aws_iam_role.invocation_role.arn}"
}
```